# unable to load external javascript file in codeigniter view

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, include

I have the following directory structure

```
*application
*media
*system
```

I place my js files inside the media/js folder but when i try to include the js file in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/common_functions.js"></script>
```

It gives the following error

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

and it does not load the js file.. even the jquery file.. can sombody tell me what is the problem. what I may be doing wrong ?

Comment: where do you place the `script` code with view?

Comment: it is in the application/views folder

Comment: i.e in a view file within application/views

Comment: try this:`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../media/js/common_functions.js"></script>`

Comment: the problem is not in the path..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10928/discussion-between-thecodeparadox-and-faizan-ali)

Comment: are you using `.htaccess`? the URL might have been rewritten by htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../media/js/common_functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: actually it do works fine If i give the absolute path.. thanks for your help !! cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$config['javascript_location'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/themes/js/jquery/';
```

*To initialize the jQuery class manually in your controller constructor, use the `$this->load->library` function:*

```
$this->load->library('jquery');
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

For standard and useful approach, try this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>media/js/common_functions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

freaking hell..!
wasted like half an hr on this. I used the [url guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) to remove index.php.
Now I had my stuff in public directory in the root folder with .htaccess file as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

So just make sure the folder is included in the RewriteCond $1 ... line as follows

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|**public**|robots\.txt)
```

Hope this helps someone.